# React.js using onclick function to render a table

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I have an array of objects coming from two different api. the first api I am converting it to a bullet point using

tag. and the second api should be converted to a table using  tag. What I want to do is whenever I click on the bullet point it should show the table with the appropriate data. I was successfully able to get the data from both apis.

The main problem I am having is, the onClick function. First, after mapping the bullet point, the onclick function treat it as one gigantic click button. they are not seperated. Second, when I tried to hard code it , since they are only 8 bullet points. I was not able to get the data on a table.

I start coding just about a month and half ago, I have been trying everything I know for the last five days. At this point I ran out of ideas.
note that this is an example of only the fisrt table i have 8 more.

Please Help me guys thank you!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const reqMenu = "fake link";
  
  const reqDescription = "fake link";
  
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  
  const [description, setDescription] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getReq()
    getDesc()

  },[]);

  const getReq = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(reqMenu);
    const data = await response.json()
    setRecipes(data)
    // console.log(data)
  };

  const getDesc = async () => {
    const response= await fetch(reqDescription);
    const data = await response.json()
    setDescription(data)
    // console.log(data)
  }
  
  const ss = description.filter((e) =>  (e.short_name.startsWith("SS")))

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Menu Categories</h1>

        <div>
          <ul>
          {recipes.map((recipe ,id, index) => (
              <li key={id} onClick={() => 
                {if(index[0] = recipes[0]["short_name"]){
                    return <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                    {ss.map((s) =>{
                      <tr key={id}>
                      <td>{s.name}</td>
                      <td>{s.description}</td>
                    </tr>
                    })}
                  </table>
                  }}}>
               {recipe.name}-({recipe.short_name})
              </li>
          ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` doesn't accept a return value. What you want to do is conditionally render the components based on state from the `onClick`.

[`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) also does not have an `id` argument.

Also, JavaScript comparison is done using `==` or `===`. Using a single `=` will do assignment, not comparison.

```
const initialListState = recipes.map(() => false);
const [listState, setListState] = useState(initialListState);

return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Menu Categories</h1>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {recipes.map((recipe, index) => (
            <li
              key={index}
              onClick={() => {
                const newListState = [...listState];
                newListState[index] = true;
                setListState(newListState);
              }
            >
              <table>
                <thead
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {listState[index] && (
                    ss.map((s, sindex) => (
                      <tr key={sindex}>
                        <td>{s.name}</td>
                        <td>{s.description}</td>
                      </tr>
                    )
                  }
                </tbody>
              </table>
              {recipe.name}-({recipe.short_name})
            </li>
          }
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```